# Proving commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring in which $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R$ where $x^2$ of course denotes $x\cdot x$.

- **a.** prove that $x+x=0$, for all $x \in R$
- **b.** prove that $R$ is commutative.

I have done part **a** but how do you do part **b**?

Comment: @rschwieb: Surely this has been asked $\approx 10$ times on math.SE and it costs 2 seconds to find this via google, but sometimes it is good to give an answer anyway so that the OP doesn't just copy complete solutions.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg: Given a choice between A) (maybe) preventing a single user from successfully fishing a full answer and B) keeping our body of answers as organized as possible, I feel B is the clear winner. The chances of A being successful already seem incredibly slim in a case like this. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Insert $x=a+b$ into the identity $x^2=x$.

Comment: Im supposed to prove that for all x,y in R, xy=yx right. So should I just let x=a+b and let y just be y?

Comment: No. Insert $a=x+y$ into $a^2=a$.

Comment: The trick is to play with $(a+b)^2$, as the hint says.

Comment: Are we talking about part b? Cuz I have done part a.

Comment: I think the same hint works for part a, but making $b=a$

Comment: I really dont know how to do it.... part b that is. I tried considering associativity of addition but got no where

Comment: I still can't do it...... there needs to be another element in R introduced to prove multiplicative commutativity but what do you do with thw other element say y in R?

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $xy=yx$ for given elements $x,y \in X$. This is equivalent to $xy+yx=0$ by a.

There is nothing we can exploit from $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$. We have to take some element which relates $x$ and $y$. So what about $x+y$?

We have $(x+y)^2=x+y$. Now expand the left hand side, cancel $x$ and $y$, and you are done.

Comment: So x^2+2xy+y^2=x+y so x+2xy+y=x+y so 2xy=0 and so does xy+yx=0 so u equate them to get xy=yx?

Comment: The binomial formula $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ does not hold in noncommutative rings. But we have (by the distributive law) $(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2$.

Comment: but how did you just get $x^2+xy+yx+y^2$ instead of $x^2+xy+xy+^2$? how did it change from xy+xy to xy+yx?

Comment: Please think a bit about it. Calculate $(x+y) \cdot (x+y)$ by hand. Recall the ring axioms.

Comment: Ok done it now.